# How to render jsx file in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

I am trying to integrate React Contact foam with MYSQL Workbence using Flask.
I created the db initialization, model using SQLAlchemy but I am facing issue in render_template.
Can I render contact.jsx file instead of index.html file? if yes, How can I do it?
Please Help!

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


# create a flask instance
app = Flask(__name__)
# Add Database
#scp.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql:username:password@localhost/db_name'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:@localhost/student_career_prediction'

# Initialize the database
mysql = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Create Model same name as in database
# by Default nullable is true


class ContactUs(mysql.Model):
    First_Name = mysql.Column(mysql.String(200),unique=False,nullable=False)
    Last_Name = mysql.Column(mysql.String(
        200), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    Email = mysql.Column(mysql.String(100), nullable=False)
    Description = mysql.Column(mysql.String(500), nullable=False)


@app.route('/Contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Contact():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Add Entry to Database
        fname = request.form.get('fname')
        lname = request.form.get('lname')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        msg = request.form.get('msg')
        entry = ContactUs(First_Name=fname, Last_Name=lname,Email=email, Description=msg)
        mysql.session.add(entry)
        mysql.session.commit()

    return render_template('Contact.jsx')


# these is to display the code in browser
# debug=True means display errors on browser.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like it is possible to directly render the `App.jsx` file.

But a workaround would be to build the React app. This creates a directory called `build/` which contains an `index.html` you could then pass to the user. Just keep in mind that you eventually need to set the `template_folder` property or rename the `build/` directory.
Also you need set the `static_folder` property or move `build/static/`.
Possibly this also has some downsides if you wanna use flasks templating.

---

I tested this with the React app that gets created when using `npx create-react-app` and the following python code:

**t.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My folder looked something like that (after renaming/moving things around)

```
my_app/
|- t.py
|- src/
   |- ... (React sources)
|- templates/ (previously `build/`)
   |- index.html
   |- ... (other files created by the build)
|- static/ (previously `build/static/`)
   |- ... (all static files created by the build)
```

And it gives me the following outputs:

- Browser (screenshot, but it's spinning):
  [image: site in brower]
- Terminal:
  [image: logs in terminal]